# "no such file to load -- bundler" error when booting redmine with passenger standalone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, redmine, passenger

I've been searching all over the internet (well, kind of) for the solution to this error, but to no avail. A few of people out there have this error, but their solutions just don't work for my case.

I'm trying to set up redmine with passenger (standalone version, not nginx nor apache bundler - I have some reasons not to). When I boot up redmine with `passenger start -e production -d` the error `no such file to load -- bundler` appears.

When, of course, I have bundle installed:

```
# gem list -d bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.21)
    Authors: AndrÃ© Arko, Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/bundler
    Homepage: http://gembundler.com
    Installed at: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

    The best way to manage your application's dependencies
```

And (looks like) my gem, ruby and such stuffs are in correct forms:

```
# gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.4.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I've followed like all possible solutions learned from other sources. I've even created a symbolic link for bundler from `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8` to `/root/.gem/ruby/1.8` following another thread on StackOver flow (well, just in case). It just doesn't work. Everytime I try to boot up, that `no such file to load -- bundler` strikes.

Could anyone help me on this? I'm not in any ways a Rails guru.

Answer (score 0):

I think ou just use different users for installing gem and for passenger running. So paths of one user not available for other. Maybe you install gem as a simple user and run passenger as a root or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Denis, but I used root account for both tasks. Actually, all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running passenger via bundler?

```
bundle exec passenger start -e production -d
```